# toggleClass not working properly in ajax case

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Below is my simple code, in which want to bookmark the code like Gmail style.

> $(this).toggleClass('favorited');

above statement is not working. star is not becoming the yellow one after getting the ajax response.
but if you put above statement outside ajax block it working. not able to understand why it is happen.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.star {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('http://www.technicalkeeda.com/img/images/star-off.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;  
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    float:left;
}   

.star.favorited {
     text-indent: -5000px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('http://www.technicalkeeda.com/img/images/star-on.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;   
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    float:left;
}

span{
color: #2864B4;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.technicalkeeda.com/js/javascripts/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.star').click(function() {
                var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');             

                $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "http://www.technicalkeeda.com/demos/bookmark",
                        cache: false,               
                        data:{'bookmarkId': id},
                        success: function(response){
                            alert('response' +response);
                             if(response=='true'){                                  
                                 $(this).toggleClass('favorited');                                               
                            }else{
                                alert('Sorry Unable bookmark..');
                            }   

                        },
                        error: function(){                      
                            alert('Error while request..');
                        }
                     });
          });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1000"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="star" ></a><span>Php CodeIgniter Server Side Form Validation Example</span></div>
<div id="2000"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="star"></a><span>Live Search Using Jquery Ajax, Php Codeigniter and Mysql</span></div>
<div id="3000"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="star"></a><span>Voting system Using jQuery Ajax and Php Codeigniter Framework</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes if you hardcode response as true , still not working

Answer (score 5):

`this` in the ajax callback is not the `.star` element, it is a jqXHR object.  Do this:

```
$(".star").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    /* snip */
    if (response == 'true') {
        $this.toggleClass('favorited');
    /* snip */
```

Comment: right-o! Just out of curiosity, I see a lot of assignment of $this in these cases. Is there any real benefit to this naming convention over any basic string like elem?

Comment: @KaiQing I tend to name variables containing jQuery collections starting with a `$` regardless of what they are, so `$this` just sort of came out of that automatically.  There's no benefit other than clarity; if it's not clear to you / your development team, feel free to use something that is

Answer (score 2):

$(this) is no longer within scope in your response. You could reference it like so...

```
$('.star').click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
```

then later in your response call

```
elem.toggleClass('favorited');
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep (almost everything) the same, set the context of the ajax call:

$.ajax({
           context: this,
           success: function () {...}
   });

On another note, I just got done recommending something similar to another person in regard to how to set up click events...

```
$('document.body').on('click', '.star', function () {....});
```

Will give you the same functionality, improve the performance and automatically accommodate any items added or removed to the document with the star class.